# Regex find 2 words separated by one or two words

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regex that checks if there is an occurrence of this pattern: " in " followed by 1 to 3 words (which have no capitalised letter) followed by " Beijing". Any ideas?

Examples that match the pattern:
"in southern Beijing"
"in the coast of Beijing"

Examples that do NOT match the pattern:
"in essence this is true for Beijing" (too many words in between)
"in Northern Beijing" (word in between has first letter capitalised)

Comment: Please clarify your question with actual examples and expected output.

Comment: Wait, so you want one or three words in between `in` and `Beijing` but not two? Oh, nevermind I see -- there are two `is` in that second example ;)

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do it:

`in ([a-z]+ ){1,3}Beijing`

Comment: Perfect, it works! (with {1,3} as I edited my original question). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Except the question was updated for 1-3 ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should match all your examples (depending on the language/flavor you use):

```
in ([a-z]+ ){1,3}Beijing
```

See the [demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/nH7gI2).

Note: there is no space preceeding `in`, as it wasn't in your examples. So if there has to be a space you have to add it.

Explanation:

```
in        #matches "in "
([a-z]+ ) #matches lower-case characters until the next space
{1,3}     #preceeding group is matched between 1 and 3 times
Beijing   #matches "Beijing"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in \([a-z]\+ \)\{1,2\}Beijing
```

The need for backslashes will vary depending on your environment, but this should work in vim.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the language, so this may not work.

```
in +([a-z]+ +){1,3}Beijing
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/qX4iA5